# Tableau: How to create a calculated field that has multiple conditions and only works against other values in the same pane

Tags: if-statement, calculated-columns, tableau-desktop, pane

In the screenshot below you'll see that I have multiple **Vendors** with their own **Activity_ID**s.
There is a calculated column (called **Modified Capacity**) that tries to replace the placeholder value of 1000 with the max value from the **Customer Count** column.

[Screenshot of current Tableau layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXegE.png)

I've used the following Calc Field to get the pictured result but as you can see, the max value being returned is row-based and I need to find the max value based on Activity_ID.

`IF MAX([Capacity]) = 1000`

`THEN MAX([Customer Count])`

`ELSEIF  MAX([Capacity]) <> 1000`

`THEN MAX ([Capacity])`

`END`

I appreciate any help.

I'm very new to posting so please excuse any rookie mistakes.

Jonathan

Comment: You may want to try using a [FIXED Level of Detail Expression](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm) and wrapping your IF statement inside that. Something like `{FIXED [Activity_ID] : (your above if statement)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [LODs functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm) for this purpose.

On your specifical problem, probably these three calculated fields would be helpful.

**Max capacity per vendor and activity**

```
// Max_capacity
{FIXED [Vendor],[Activity ID] : MAX([Capacity])}
```

**Max customer count**

```
// Max_customers
{FIXED [Vendor],[Activity ID] : MAX([Customer Count])}
```

**Modified capacity**

```
//Modified capacity
IF [Max_capacity] = 1000
THEN [Max_customers]
ELSE [Max_capacity]
END
```

Comment: I created the Max Cap and Max Customer calc fields and then used them in a third calc field and it work perfectly. MUFF's suggestion to add the FIXED LOD expression to my original calc field also worked. TY!